# Lowering MySQL Full Text Word Length

Tags: mysql, vps

Hello I just installed MySQL 5.6 on my vps and I realized numbers were not searching in full text searches. Then I came across this article http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html

It says:

"***The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by the ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len system variables. (See Section 5.1.4, “Server System Variables”.) The default minimum value is four characters; the default maximum is version dependent. If you change either value, you must rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes. For example, if you want three-character words to be searchable, you can set the ft_min_word_len variable by putting the following lines in an option file:
[mysqld]
ft_min_word_len=3
Then restart the server and rebuild your FULLTEXT indexes***"

What does this mean. I am kind of a noob at ssh and vps's and this really confuses me.

Can I do this through a vps? (Digital Ocean)

If so, please lead me in the right direction so I can figure this out.

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

The word lenghts there is the minimum word lenghts mysql will use to build it's fulltext search's index.

In example 'test' will get indexed, but not 'sex'. That limit the size of your fulltext index.

If you want it lower, then like they told you need to set the option and you have to rebuild your table index.